# MACD in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I get an error when adding to TV: Error at 11:51 'Object has no field histogram'. I want to have an alert / arrow when 9 ema crosses 70 wma and is above 200 ema and when the histogram of both MACD 2hr and 12 hr timeframes are above 0. I cant get my head around it. What am i doing wrong. Hope someone can help.

Here is the code:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Pardon3000

//@version=5
indicator("Pine Script Example", overlay=true)

// Define the indicators
ema9 = ta.ema(close, 9)
wma70 = ta.wma(close, 70)
ema200 = ta.ema(close, 200)
macd2h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "2h", ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9).histogram)[0] 
macd12h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "12h", ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9).histogram)[0]

// Plot the indicators
plot(ema9, color=color.blue)
plot(wma70, color=color.red)
plot(ema200, color=color.green)

// Check for crossover condition
crossover_condition = ta.crossover(ema9, wma70) and ema9 > ema200 and macd2h[1] > 0 and macd12h[1] > 0

// Generate an alert if crossover condition is true
alertcondition(crossover_condition, title="Crossover Alert", message="EMA9 crossed over WMA70 and is above EMA200 on current timeframe and on 2h timeframe. MACD is above 0 on 2h and 12h timeframe.")

// Plot an arrow up under the candle if crossover condition is true
plotshape(crossover_condition ? low : na, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
```

Tried to change the code

Answer (score 0):

There is no dot notation where you can get only the histogram value out of macd.

You just need to calculate the macd, then pass those values to the security function.

```
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
[macdLine_htf, signalLine_htf, histLine_htf] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "2h", [macdLine, signalLine, histLine])
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you place the snippet in the full code, because i'm not sure how to implement it, also for the 12h timeframe.